# Illegal invocation while intercepting method calls with javascript proxy

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-proxy

Can someone explain the following output

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target,key, receiver){
    return new Proxy(Reflect.get(target, key, receiver),handler);
  }, 
  apply: function(target, thisArg, args){
    Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args);
  }
}

var p = new Proxy(window, handler);
p.alert("Alert"); // Throws illegal invocation error

var alias = p.alert;
alias("Alert") // Even this works which is baffling for me

var p = new Proxy(Reflect.get(window, "alert"), handler);
p("Alert"); // works as expected
```

The first statement throws an illegal invocation error, whereas the second one doesn't. Both of them look identical to me, and I don't understand how the first statement doesn't have the required `this` context during `Reflect.apply`

Comment: For @ibrahimmahrir’s answer as it applies to your proxy, see the error produced by `alert.call(new Proxy(window, {}), "alert")`

Comment: When a function is invoked without an explicit context, the context will be `window`. Explicit context: in both `obj.func` and `func.call(obj)` the context will be `obj`.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for that wonderful example, it actually answers the question. So passing a proxy object of a target as a context is not the same as passing the target itself as the context, which actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that `alert` needs `window` as context, otherwise it throws that error. It has nothing to do with proxies. These two examples throw the same error:

```js
var obj = {};
alert.call(obj, "hello!");           // doesn't work!
```

and:

```js
var obj = { alert: alert };
obj.alert("hello!");                 // doesn't work!
```

In your code if you set the context of `p.alert` to `window`, it works:

```
p.alert.call(window, "hello!");      // works!
```

```js
var handler = {
  get: function(target, key, receiver) {
    return new Proxy(Reflect.get(target, key, receiver), handler);
  },
  apply: function(target, thisArg, args) {
    Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args);
  }
}

var p = new Proxy(window, handler);
p.alert.call(window, "Alert");
```

The other two examples from your code work because the context is `window`.

Comment: Thanks I'll mark this as the answer, but the reason the proxy here becomes relevant is because if I call Reflect.apply inside the get handler itself, this problem no longer occurs, cause now I am calling the method with the target context captured.